# How to prove that the pointreflection at the midpoint of two several points out of a regular pointlattice fix the lattice?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, symmetry

> How to prove that the pointreflection at the midpoint of two several points $A,B\in\mathfrak{L}$ in a regular pointlattice $\mathfrak{L}$ fix
>   the lattice $\mathfrak{L}$?

We call $\mathfrak{L}\subset\mathbb{E}$ a *regular pointlattice* in the euclidian plane $\mathbb{E}$ if and only if:

$$\exists A,B,C\in\mathfrak{L}\text{ non collinar}:\mathfrak{L}=\{\tau_{A,B}^i\circ\tau_{A,C}^j(A)\mid i,j\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$

in wich $\tau_{A,B},\tau_{A,C}\in Iso(\mathbb{E})$ are translations from Point $A$ to $B$ and accordingly $A$ to $C$.

my attampt...

**proof:**
Let $A,B$ be two serveral points in the pointlattice $\mathfrak{L}$.

Further more there is an arbitray point $P\in\mathbb{E}$.
If the midpoint $MP[A,B]$ lies in $\mathfrak{L}$: $\exists n,m\in\mathbb{Z}:P=\tau_1^m\circ\tau_2^n(MP[A,B])$, while $\tau_1,\tau_2\in Iso(\mathbb{E})$ are generators of generating elemnts of the regular pointlattice. It is easy to see, that $\sigma_{MP[A,B]}(A)=\tau_1^{-m}\circ\tau_2^{-n}(MP[A,B])$.

But what if $MP[A,B]\notin\mathfrak{L}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems easier just to say that $\mathcal{L} = \{na+mb:n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ for fixed linearly independent $a, b\in\mathbb{E}$.  What is $\tau_{A,B}$ if not a function which has $\tau_{A,B}(x)=x+(B-A)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{E}$?

Wolog one of the points is $(0,0)$; let the other be $na+mb$.  The midpoint is ${1\over 2}(na+mb)$.  The reflection $r$ in that midpoint takes $z\in\mathbb{E}$ to $r(z)={1\over 2}(na+mb)-(z-{1\over 2}(na+mb))=$ $na+mb-z$, so if $z=n'a+m'b\in\mathcal{L}$, then $r(z)=(n-n')a+(m-m')b\in\mathcal{L}$, as we wished to prove.